# how can i setup and use test server in Sabre

Tags: sabre

we have a sabre enterprise API. we want to test different test cases before going to production.

Can anyone suggest to me how can I setup Sabre development/testing server or use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have webservices credentials in production environment, the same are enabled in CERT but might have been disabled after a few days. You should contact webservices@sabre.com to unlock your credentials.

More help on [Environments](https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/developer-guides/environments)

```
How to Access Our Environments 
Your Sabre account manager can grant you access to our environments, which can be accessed via the following URLs:
REST
Certification/Test: https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com
Production: https://api.havail.sabre.com

SOAP
Certification/Test: https://sws-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com
Production: https://webservices.havail.sabre.com
```

HTH